# Dynamically re-order tiles based on different size browser or mobile screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

Whatever screen is being used to view the page, I would like to show as many tiles as possible. Different scenarios include:

- Mobile browswer (iPhone, Android)
- iPad or Android Table or Kindle Fire
- Narrow Browser window (safari, chrome, ie, firefox, operta, etc)
- Full screen Browser window

One solution I thought of was to use **960.gs** and **adaptive.js** ... however, when I set the size of the div, for example:

> div class="tile grid_4"

I noticed that adaptive.js would resize the tile (becase the different .css files resize the columns)... However, I need to keep a fixed tile size (310px X 450px)....

**Perhaps I need to dynamically rename the div class so that the # of columns x col width = 310px?**

One site that does this is http://pinterest.com

And to see what each **tile** looks like, please check out http://jsfiddle.net/hagope/76jjp/

[image: Tiles on Different Size Browsers]

Comment: Please provide some simplified HTML and CSS here. (It looks to me like you only need to give each "tile" a `float: left` style and some margins.)

Comment: Pinterest does it differently than you should, because the tile sizes vary in height.  Their solution, more complex, orders the tiles in vertical columns.  George's answer below should be sufficient for fixed sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at CSS3 [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries). I recommend you read A List Apart's fantastic article on **[Responsive Web Design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/)**, which covers the subject and is a good starting point.

After you've got the basics sorted, you can target specific devices using the [`device-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries#device-width) query. To target high-density displays (e.g. the iPhone4's retina display) you can look into the [`device-pixel-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries#-moz-device-pixel-ratio) query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: P.S. Media queries are really nice and pretty widely supported, but don't dismiss `float` because of it. What you want to accomplish can easily be done with `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you want, this should be doable with only CSS.  Have each tile styled as `display: block` (along with your fixed width and height), and then wrap each tile in a `display: inline; float: left;` container element.  Add any more CSS you want for style, and it should work fine.

Here's an example: http://gpittarelli.com/so_examples/inline_tiles.htm

Comment: This is good, the problem with this is that the columns are not centered on the page (the are all left) is there a quick CSS fix for that?

Comment: How can the columns be centered, when you are trying to fit as many as you can?  I'm not quite sure what you're aiming for, but you could try wrapping the tiles in a container element (`div` or whatever you fancy) and centering that container.

Comment: Seriously, have a look at **this [example](http://www.alistapart.com/d/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-FINAL.html)** from the ALA [article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/). A lot can be done with simple floats, but in the end, media queries are a lot more powerful. And you don't have to worry about Internet Explorer; you can use [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to add media query support.